I was trying to implement the Round Robin CPU scheduling algorithm in C, and this happened
No compilation error, no logical error (I believe). But the thing is, there is no output at all! If you see my code, I set up test print statements at places, including one at the extreme beginning of main(), even that is not getting printed. I am clueless.
I would be glad if someone could help me figure out what's going on.
Here is my code:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

struct process
{
    int PID;
    int AT;     // arrival time
    int BT;     // burst time
    int ST;     // start time
    int CT;     // completion time
    int TAT;    // turn-around time
    int WT;     // waiting time
    int RT;     // response time
    int remaining_BT;   // remaining burst time for round robin
    
};

#define PROCESS_LIMIT 100
#define TIME_QUANTUM 2
struct process processes[PROCESS_LIMIT];        // array to store processes
void display(int i);
void wait_time(int n, int m);

void create_process()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (int i = 0; i < PROCESS_LIMIT; i++)
    {
        processes[i].PID = (i + 1);
    
        // arrival time
        int at = (rand() % 10) + 1;
        if (i != 0)
        {
            processes[i].AT = processes[i-1].AT + at;
        }
        else
        {
            processes[i].AT = at;
        }
        
        // burst time
        int bt = (rand() % 10) + 1;
        processes[i].BT = bt;
        processes[i].remaining_BT = bt;
        
        processes[i].CT = 0;
        processes[i].TAT = 0;
        processes[i].WT = 0;
        processes[i].RT = -1;
        
    }
}

void dispatcher()
{
    // FCFS algorithm
    int current_time = 0;
    int processes_completed = 0;
    int i = 0;

    printf("test 1");
    
    while (processes_completed < PROCESS_LIMIT)
    {
        // check if the current process is ready to run
        if (processes[i].remaining_BT > 0 && processes[i].AT <= current_time)
        {
            if (processes[i].RT == -1)
                processes[i].RT = current_time - processes[i].AT;
                
            int time_to_run = processes[i].remaining_BT <= TIME_QUANTUM ? processes[i].remaining_BT : TIME_QUANTUM;
            
            processes[i].ST = current_time;
            current_time += time_to_run;
            processes[i].remaining_BT -= time_to_run;
            
            if (processes[i].remaining_BT == 0) // check if the process has finished
            {
                processes[i].CT = current_time;
                processes[i].TAT = processes[i].CT - processes[i].AT;
                processes[i].WT = processes[i].TAT - processes[i].BT;
                processes_completed++;

                printf("Processes completed: %d\n", processes_completed);
            }
        }
        
        i = (i + 1) % PROCESS_LIMIT;
        
    }
}

void display(int i)
{
    if (i == 0)
    {
        printf("PID  AT  BT  ST  CT  TAT  WT  RT\n");
    }
    
    printf("%d    %d  %d  %d  %d  %d  %d  %d\n", processes[i].PID, processes[i].AT, processes[i].BT, processes[i].ST, processes[i].CT, processes[i].TAT, processes[i].WT, processes[i].RT);
    
}

int main()
{
    printf("test main 1");
    create_process();
    dispatcher();
    
    printf("tester");
    
    // display
    for (int i = 0; i < PROCESS_LIMIT; i++)
    {
        display(i);
    }

    return 0;
}


Start by having just a single process. Does everything work as it should? When you add one process, how about then? Run and test multiple times. Continue increasing until the error comes, and then debug your program.

And are you really implementing a round-robin algorithm? The comment in your dispatcher function says FCFS (which I assume means First Come, First Served).

Regarding the comment stating FCFS, I forgot to replace it after completing my FCFS code. I reused parts of it and the comment came from there.

When adding printf statements to monitor program flow, including a newline character (\n) at the end. This causes the output to be written to the terminal immediately. Otherwise, the output is written to a buffer and stays there. Generally, always end printf statements with a newline unless you are deliberately writing only part of a line that is to be completed later.

The tip regarding the print value remaining in the buffer in the absence of a newline character did work in this case!

Eithter add \n to the printed buffer or use fflush(stdout); after each printf statement.
The reason for that is because printf doesn't print immediately, until the stdout buffer is flushed.
stdout buffer is flushed if :

you add a new line
get input to stdin
flush it using fflush.
the program is terminated

Here's the updated code. Note that this solution only solves the printing issue you have. There's a bug in your program that causes the while loop to go infinite, but this question is focused on why it's not printing.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

struct process
{
    int PID;
    int AT;     // arrival time
    int BT;     // burst time
    int ST;     // start time
    int CT;     // completion time
    int TAT;    // turn-around time
    int WT;     // waiting time
    int RT;     // response time
    int remaining_BT;   // remaining burst time for round robin
    
};

#define PROCESS_LIMIT 100
#define TIME_QUANTUM 2
struct process processes[PROCESS_LIMIT];        // array to store processes
void display(int i);
void wait_time(int n, int m);

void create_process()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (int i = 0; i < PROCESS_LIMIT; i++)
    {
        processes[i].PID = (i + 1);
    
        // arrival time
        int at = (rand() % 10) + 1;
        if (i != 0)
        {
            processes[i].AT = processes[i-1].AT + at;
        }
        else
        {
            processes[i].AT = at;
        }
        
        // burst time
        int bt = (rand() % 10) + 1;
        processes[i].BT = bt;
        processes[i].remaining_BT = bt;
        
        processes[i].CT = 0;
        processes[i].TAT = 0;
        processes[i].WT = 0;
        processes[i].RT = -1;
        
    }
}

void dispatcher()
{
    // FCFS algorithm
    int current_time = 0;
    int processes_completed = 0;
    int i = 0;

    printf("test 1\n");
    
    while (processes_completed < PROCESS_LIMIT)
    {
        // check if the current process is ready to run
        if (processes[i].remaining_BT > 0 && processes[i].AT <= current_time)
        {
            if (processes[i].RT == -1)
                processes[i].RT = current_time - processes[i].AT;
                
            int time_to_run = processes[i].remaining_BT <= TIME_QUANTUM ? processes[i].remaining_BT : TIME_QUANTUM;
            
            processes[i].ST = current_time;
            current_time += time_to_run;
            processes[i].remaining_BT -= time_to_run;
            
            if (processes[i].remaining_BT == 0) // check if the process has finished
            {
                processes[i].CT = current_time;
                processes[i].TAT = processes[i].CT - processes[i].AT;
                processes[i].WT = processes[i].TAT - processes[i].BT;
                processes_completed++;

                printf("Processes completed: %d\n", processes_completed);
            }
        }
        
        i = (i + 1) % PROCESS_LIMIT;
    }
}

void display(int i)
{
    if (i == 0)
    {
        printf("PID  AT  BT  ST  CT  TAT  WT  RT\n");
    }
    
    printf("%d    %d  %d  %d  %d  %d  %d  %d\n", processes[i].PID, processes[i].AT, processes[i].BT, processes[i].ST, processes[i].CT, processes[i].TAT, processes[i].WT, processes[i].RT);
}

int main()
{
    printf("test main 1\n");
    create_process();
    dispatcher();
    
    printf("tester\n");
    
    // display
    for (int i = 0; i < PROCESS_LIMIT; i++)
    {
        display(i);
    }

    return 0;
}

Add a printf statement after you update the i to see what I'm talking about. Hope this helped.

The newline trick did help. Not sure why the buffer works like this, but it does solve this part of the issue.

I've update my answer to include the reason. I tried my best to look at documentation and see why it only gets flushed if there's a new line or a new input to stdin exists, but couldn't really find it. Will add it to my answer if I see it somewhere.

here's a source that can help, but it's just an answer to a question on a blog, not official documentation or source.

@AbitathaRoy one more thing to note is that stdout also gets flushed when the program is terminated.

All of your processes start with a non-zero arrival time, and you start current_time at zero, so body of the if (processes[i].remaining_BT > 0 && processes[i].AT <= current_time) statement is never entered, and the program never increases current_time. Then nothing ever happens in the loop.

I don't think all my processes are beginning with arrival time zero, as while creating each process, the values for AT and BT are randomised and initialised.

@AbitathaRoy: processes[0].AT is set from int at = (rand() % 10) + 1;. That is clearly not zero because rand() % 10 produces a value in [0, 9], and adding 1 makes it greater. Every other AT is set with processes[i].AT = processes[i-1].AT + at;, which increases from a previous value, so none of them are zero.

Got it, got that part.

So guys, it was mainly some error with the C buffer. This was the first time I encountered this, and the solution to this was to write fflush(stdout) after the printf() statements. Flushing out the buffer works.
Note: The program might still need several runs and might completely execute only once in three attempts.
